# adding the .val to the autocomplete

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to implement this jQuery auto complete function but the problem is this i need the value of the previous input field. getting the value from the previous is easy, I just dont know how to add it to the call

the call for the previous value is on top of the document.ready and this doesnt get called when the user types

I NEED to pass it in with this serviceurl like this

```
song_path(value)
```

but that fails

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
            value = $('#request_artist').val();
        $('#song_artist').autocomplete({
          serviceUrl: '<%= song_path() %>',
          minChars:1,
          width: 300,
          delimiter: /(,|;)\s*/,
          deferRequestBy: 0, //miliseconds
          params: { artists: 'Yes' },
        });
    });
```

So i basically need something like this

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#song_artist').autocomplete({
          serviceUrl: '<%= song_path() %>'$('#request_artist').val(),
          minChars:1,
          width: 300,
          delimiter: /(,|;)\s*/,
          deferRequestBy: 0, //miliseconds
          params: { artists: 'Yes' },
        });
    });
```

but this fails

Comment: You want to use the value from *another* input for the autocomplete?  I'm not following here, shouldn't you be wanting the `#song_artist`'s input, since the behavior is based completely around auto-completing an input?

Comment: I was trying to use the artist name and only select his or her songs so i was using that as the pass in but i realized i was going in the wrong direction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will not be able to use `song_path` helper, as it is rendered before getting to the browser, you can't call that function in the browser. Instead you need to write something like

```
serviceUrl: '/songs/' + $('#request_artist').val(),
```

if `$('#request_artist').val()` returns the id.